# RabbitMQ for chat channel-multicasting

Tags: rabbitmq, rabbitmq-exchange

Let‘s assume I have a simple chat application where some clients can post messages to some channel X and some clients want to subscribe to all messages in X (channel-based multicasting).

Would I create a Fanout Exchange for each channel or is there a way to utilize Topic for this use-case?

Also a new client that is added to a channel X should be able to read the last message from X. How is that done?

Would it scale for millions of channels?

(Or should I rather look at MQTT?)

Answer (score 0):

A RabbitMQ Topic Exchange (using pub/sub) is definitely an option to create this kind of distribution pattern... producers would ensure their messages' routing key corresponds to "Channel X", and consumers (via their queues) would bind to this Exchange with a matching pattern. This should mean you don't need to have a specific Exchange for each of your channels.  But unknown whether it can scale to millions of channels.

If considering other messaging technologies, maybe take a look at Solace? (FYI, I work for them).  We actually have a free Udemy dev course where you build a chat app!  https://www.udemy.com/fundamentals-of-solace-development/. Solace supports MQTT natively if you want to go that route, and also has a built-in Replay capability that could be used to retrieve the last *n* messages on a given topic.